# How to dynamically show table header and rows properly from a JSON file

Tags: php, json, database, html-table

I am trying to figure out how to show a JSON file into a custom HTML table and first get the objects keys, then the values and display them into my table.

Here's a code I'm trying:

```
    <!-- table header -->
    <thead>
       <?php 
       // Load the file
       $jsonStr = file_get_contents("Users.json");
       // Decode the JSON data into a PHP array.
       $jsonObjs = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

       foreach($jsonObjs as $key => $value) {
         $obj = $jsonObjs[$i];
         echo '<th>'.$obj[$key].'</th>';
       } 

       echo '
       </thead><!-- ./ table header -->

       <tbody>
       <!-- table row -->
       <tr>';

       foreach($jsonObjs as $key => $value) {
          $obj = $jsonObjs[$i];
          echo '<td>'.$obj[$value].'</td>';
       }
   ?>
<td>
<a href="#a" class="btn btn-info btn-fill" onclick="showNotification('Object successfully edited!')"><i class="nc-icon nc-settings-90"></i> Edit</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#a" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill" onclick="showDeleteModal()"><i class="nc-icon nc-simple-remove"></i> Delete</a>
</td>
</tr><!-- ./ table row -->
```

Here's my `Users.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "objID":"u7uSoWCPW8",
        "string":"bobby",
        "createdOn":"2018-09-17  08:08:30",
        "updatedOn":"2018-09-17 08:08:30",
        "number":111,
        "boolean":true,
        "array":["john","sarah"],
        "pointer2":{
            "type":"__pointer",
            "objID":"dfg56FdE",
            "className":"Users"
        }
    },
    {
        "objID":"rvLXpsN7Cb",
        "string":"bobby",
        "createdOn":"2018-09-17  09:03:30",
        "updatedOn":"2018-09-17 09:03:30",
        "number":111,
        "boolean":true,
        "array":["john","sarah"],
        "pointer2":{
            "type":"__pointer",
            "objID":"dfg56FdE",
            "className":"Users"
        }
    }
]
```

When I run my HTML page with the table, I get only the 2 buttons at the end of the row (and 1 row only). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why read and decode the file twice?

Comment: well, as I said I'm a newbie, so I'm trying to figure out something that it's not so clear to me, I thought that was the right way to separate table header with rows :) Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @mplungjanI've edited the code, so now it reads and decodes my JSON file once, thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: YW. I would do it on the client instead - saves bandwidth. I do not do enough php to see the issue at a glance

Comment: i’m not able to do that, and what i need to do is read and edit json files, i already have a php file that creates json files and objects, so i have to keep working on such json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create table header first

```
foreach($jsonObjs[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
}
```

create body

```
foreach($jsonObjs as $obj) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($obj as $key => $value){
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative.

If you Ajax the file into the page,

```
fetch('Users.json').then(process);
```

you can do something like this:

```js
var tHead = document.getElementById("th"),
  tBody = document.getElementById("tb"),
  tr, td, text,
  thr = document.createElement("tr"); // this is the table header row
 
 // this whole thing goes away when you activate the fetch
 var data = [{ "objID": "u7uSoWCPW8", "string": "bobby", "createdOn": "2018-09-17 08:08:30", "updatedOn": "2018-09-17 08:08:30", "number": 111, "boolean": true, "array": ["john", "sarah"], "pointer2": { "type": "__pointer", "objID": "dfg56FdE", "className": "Users" } }, { "objID": "rvLXpsN7Cb", "string": "bobby", "createdOn": "2018-09-17 09:03:30", "updatedOn": "2018-09-17 09:03:30", "number": 111, "boolean": true, "array": ["john", "sarah"], "pointer2": { "type": "__pointer", "objID": "dfg56FdE", "className": "Users" } } ]
 
function process(data) {
  data.forEach(function(item, i) { // array
    tr = document.createElement("tr"); // create the row

    for (key in item) {
      if (i === 0) {  // save the THs from the first item
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = key;
        thr.appendChild(th);
      }
      text = []; // this is for the array and object in the item
      if (typeof item[key] == "object") {
        if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
          item[key].forEach(function(item2, j) { // Array forEach
            text.push(item2)
          });
        } else {
          for (key2 in item[key]) {
            text.push(key2 + ":" + item[key][key2]); // Object for..in
          }
        }
      } else {
        text.push(item[key]); // everything else
      }
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = text.join("<br/>");
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tBody.appendChild(tr);
  });
  tHead.appendChild(thr);
}

process(data); // to be replaced with fetch('Users.json').then(process);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead id="th"></thead>
  <tbody id="tb"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I understand. - just thought I'd try to parse your data into a table